# I need to group and summarize flat arraycollection data. Data cannot be grouped out side of app and must return arraycollection

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, grouping, arraycollection

I have flat data in my app which I will need to group, summarize, and count as I normally would with a sql query.  For this project though, it must be done in the flex app.  I need to figure out how to group my data by day or month using a datatime field in my Arraycollection, then appropriately count or summarize data in other fields.  I've used Groupingcollections before, but only when binding to hierarchical controls (like AdvancedDataGrid and Tree), but I need a resulting ArrayCollection with the grouped and summarized data.

Basically, I'm trying to access my AC like a sql table (GROUP BY MONTH(datetime), COUNT, COUNT(DISTINCT(), etc.) and I'm unsure how to do it.  Does anyone have experience doing this?

Comment: Use the filter function of the array collection.

Comment: filter function is great for "SELECT" type queries if that is all that is needed, but it's not robust enough to provide summarization and counts without customizing code for each operation myself for each use case. I giving ActionLinq a try...

Comment: It sure can, you just assign a new function. But Have fun with ActionsLinq

Answer (score 2):

You can give ActionLinq (https://bitbucket.org/briangenisio/actionlinq/wiki/Home) a try.
I've not used it myself, but I've been itching to give it a try :)

It's an implementation of Linq (from C#) in actionscript. This gives you a functional way of dealing with collections of data in a very SQL-like manner (select, group, filter, etc.).

I would characterise it like the `filter` method on steroids.

Here is an example from the website - it shows some of the SQL-like names and how the chaining works:

```
var transformed:Array =
    [-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    .where(isEven)
    .select(square)
    .distinct()
    .reverse()
    .toArray();

assertThat(transformed, array(0, 4, 16));
```

More information and examples here:
http://riarockstars.com/2011/02/07/processing-data-on-the-clientactionlinq/

Comment: ActionLinq was a great suggestion...I'll be working on implementing it this week and will post results.

Answer (score 0):

You may find that this example points you in the right direction http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2008/09/groupingcollection-example-featuring.html